# Xml Parsing in android

Tags: android

EveryOne I am doing xml parsing like This

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler{

 // ===========================================================
 // Fields
 // ===========================================================
static ArrayList<Category1> cat_list=new ArrayList<Category1>();
static ArrayList<Products> product_list=new ArrayList<Products>();
   Category1 cat;
   Products pro;
 private boolean in_outertag = false;
 private boolean in_innertag = false;
 private boolean in_mytag = false;
 private boolean in_mytag1 = false;
 private boolean in_mytag2 = false;
 private boolean in_mytag3 = false;


 private XMLDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new XMLDataSet();

 // ===========================================================
 // Getter & Setter
 // ===========================================================

 public XMLDataSet getParsedData() {
      return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
 }

 // ===========================================================
 // Methods
 // ===========================================================
 @Override
 public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
      this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new XMLDataSet();
 }

 @Override
 public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
      // Nothing to do
 }

 /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
  * <tag>
  * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
  * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
 @Override
 public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
           String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
      if (localName.equals("root")) {
           this.in_outertag = true;
      }else if (localName.equals("Categories")) {
           this.in_innertag = true;
      }else if (localName.equals("Category")) {
          cat =new Category1();
          String attrValue = atts.getValue("id");
          int i = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i);
          cat.setCatId(i+"");
          //cat_id[i]=myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i);
          //Log.i("id", cat.setCatId(i+""));
          String attrValue1 = atts.getValue("pid");
          int i1 = Integer.parseInt(attrValue1);
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i1);
          cat.setPid(i1+"");
          //p_id[i1]=myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i1);
          //Log.i("pid", myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i1)+"");
           this.in_mytag = true;
      }else if (localName.equals("title")) {
           // Extract an Attribute

          this.in_mytag1 = true;
      }else if (localName.equals("products")) {
           this.in_innertag = true;
      }else if (localName.equals("product")) {
          pro=new Products();
          String attrValue = atts.getValue("catid");
          int i = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i);
          pro.setCatId(i+"");
          //Log.i("catid", myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i)+"");
           this.in_mytag = true;
      }else if (localName.equals("name")) {
           // Extract an Attribute
          this.in_mytag2 = true;
      }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
           // Extract an Attribute
          this.in_mytag3 = true;
      }
 }

 /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
  * </tag> */
 @Override
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
           throws SAXException {
      if (localName.equals("root")) {
           this.in_outertag = false;
      }else if (localName.equals("Categories")) {
           this.in_innertag = false;
      }else if (localName.equals("Category")) {
          cat_list.add(cat);

           this.in_mytag = false;
      }else if (localName.equals("title")) {

           this.in_mytag1=false;
      }else if (localName.equals("products")) {

          this.in_innertag=false;
     }else if (localName.equals("product")) {
      product_list.add(pro);
         this.in_mytag=false;
    }else if (localName.equals("name")) {

        this.in_mytag2=false;
   }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {

       this.in_mytag3=false;
  }
 }

 /** Gets be called on the following structure:
  * <tag>characters</tag> */
 @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
      if(this.in_mytag1){
      myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
      cat.setCatName(new String(ch, start, length));
 }
      if(this.in_mytag2){
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
          pro.setProductId(new String(ch, start, length));
     }
      if(this.in_mytag3){
          String chars = new String(ch, start, length); 
            chars = chars.trim(); 
          //myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(chars);
          pro.setUrl(chars);
     }
}
```

}

I parse all thing very good but not url....

The Xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<products>

    <product catid="11">

        <name>song1</name>

        <url>http://news.google.co.in/news?edchanged=1&amp;ned=en_il</url>

    </product>
```

I got the result `ned=en_il` only

Please Help me, Where i am wrong??
Thankx

Comment: Have you tried using XPath with Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try by warping your `<url>` node into CDATA tag like this

```
<url><![CDATA[http://news.google.co.in/news?edchanged=1&ned=en_il]]></url>
```

to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using android.sax for parsing it is much easier. You can  read about it here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: I read This link Dear but not helpful for this situation. Thankx for suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be in your characters method.

This method may be called several times for a given element, your code is assuming it will only be called once. e.g. It is likely called for "http://news.google.co.in", "/news?edchanged=1&" and "ned=en_il"

If you append the characters to appropriate properties instead of setting them it will probably work.